# PhoneGap Android getJSON

Tags: android, json, cordova

I'm taking my first steps in PhoneGap with Android (How come you have to pick a platform, anyway? It's supposed to be cross-platform!). I'm trying to call a RESTful service, get some JSON in return and put it on the screen. Tutorials for this are incredibly hard to find. I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>JSON Demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON('http://MyServerIP/json/GetJobDetails/717/MyKey?callback=?',  {
    success:function(data)
    {
            data = evalJSON(data);
            $('body').append('<strong>X </strong>');
    }, 
    error: function() 
    {
     $('body').append('<strong>Error </strong>'); 
    }
});
        </script>
</head>
<body>
test 10
</body>
</html>
```

...But I get no response, neither success nor error. The server reports that it has been hit though, and returned the data. Browsing to the same URL also returns data. How come nothing appears in the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the success: and error: were killing it, ie this works:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON('http://MyServerIP/json/GetJobDetails/717/MyKey?callback=?', function(data)
    {
            data = evalJSON(data);
            $('body').append('<strong>X </strong>');        
});
        </script>
```

Comment: If you were still wondering, the reason is because `success` and `error` functions don't exist in `$.getJSON`.  It is a shorthand function [getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  To use those functions you would either have to define [global jQuery Ajax handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) or use the full `$.ajax` function

Answer (score 2):

You can find a good tutorial about Android + jquery mobile here in the official wiki of PhoneGAP here:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

For your problem Make sure this line is in phonegap app manifest file: 
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >< /uses-permission >

Plus, you can set the server headers to: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'

Good Luck!