# datatables are not updating in meteorjs

Tags: meteor, datatables, meteorite

I am working on an application using meteorjs. I am totally new to meteor. In my application I am using dataTables with meteor for shorting , pagination and searching.
This is my template code

```
<template name="questions">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {{#constant}}
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover listing"
               id="content_listing-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Questions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#each questions}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-id={{_id}} class="edit"> {{questionSubString question_text}}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}     
           </tbody>
        </table>
        {{/constant}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and my meteor code is

```
Template.questions.rendered = function () {
$("#content_listing-table").dataTable();
}

Template.questions.questions = function () {    
return Meteor.questions.find({topic_id: Session.get("currentTopicId")})
```

}

my problem is when i add a question to the database it doesn't seem on template. and generate an exception. I know this is because of datatables . and datatable is not update when document updated. i tried many examples from stackoverflow but couldn't get rid of this problem .I tried by appending row dynamically but it always give me a warning . and it doen't seems to do a right way. can i remove the datatables from the element dynamically?  help will be appreciated 
EDIT:

```
 $('#content_listing-table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
 $('#content_listing-table').dataTable().fnAddData(Meteor.questions.find().fetch());
```

I am trying to do this first empty the table and then again add the data to it. But here it is emptying the table for not adding the data again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `{{constant}}` region. This disables reactivity for that part of the template.

Try getting rid of your constant region and run meteor using `meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`. This will run meteor using the new, in progress template engine Meteor UI. There are no `constant`s or `preserve`s in Meteor UI - it's smart enough to make DOM changes at a fine-grained level, so it should work out of the box with things like jQuery plugins.

Comment: I am using constant here because i have some links in the table. If i dont use `{{constant}}` here all the links become disabled. and `<td></td>` looks empty, without any data or link

Comment: And I am using meteor 6.6

Comment: The template engine preview 5.5 is newer than the current Meteor release 0.6.6.3. As the Meteor docs say, "Content inside the `#constant` block helper is preserved exactly as-is even if the enclosing template is re-rendered.". This means no reactivity. You'll need to wait for the new template engine or use the preview release, like I said.

Comment: Okay, but when i am using meteor --release template-engine-preview-5. it doesn't display anything on the template. means it renders a blank template.

Comment: Are you still using the constant region?

Comment: No, I removed the constant region now.

Comment: I am using iron-routers package also, I think meteor --release template-engine-preview-5. has some issues with this.

Comment: Try `meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`