# JSON to html STYLED table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

We can convert a set of JSON data to html table by below code:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(val, function(k, v){
        $('<td>'+v+'</td>').appendTo(tr);
    });
    tr.appendTo('#display');
});
```

The html table is:

```
<table border='1' id="display">

    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>firstcol</th>
                <th>loc</th>
                <th>lastA</th>
                <th>mTime</th>
                <th>nTime</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>ction</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>        
</table>
```

A working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/AHv6c/ (source [jquery code to display json response to a html table using append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760661/jquery-code-to-display-json-response-to-a-html-table-using-append))

My problem is when some of the rows columns could have their own style class.

So I want to change some of the the table `<th>` to `<th class='sampleStyle'>` . Can you please let me know how should I change the java script to read the corresponding class from `th` and assign it to relevant columns (s).

Then the generated table should be something like:

```
<tr>
     <td>56036</td>
     <td class="sampleStyle">Deli</td>
     ....
```

By the way do you know better approach?

Comment: where do you get the style classes? are they saved in the data array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like http://www.jqversion.com/#!/Mdi8Kla

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var tr    = $('<tr></tr>'),
        index = 0;
    $.each(val, function(k, v){
        $('<td>'+v+'</td>').addClass(
          $('th:eq(' + index + ')').attr('class')
        ).appendTo(tr);
        index++;
    });
    tr.appendTo('#display');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td:eq(0)", tr).addClass("sampleStyle");
```

before appending tr

Comment: I want to get the class from the <th> not add a class to first td or so