# Need to catch JSON object returned from Controller and display as HTML in .cshtml file(View)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display the data returned from my controller class of type JSON in HTML table on View.

Below are the details.

Controller class

```
 ROCRespository rocrep = new ROCRespository();
    public JsonResult ROC() 
    {
        return Json(rocrep.GetAllRocDetails(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Model Class:

```
 public class ROCRespository 
{
    public List<ROC> roc;
    public ROCRespository() 
    {
        this.roc = new List<ROC>() 
        {
            new ROC(){CourseId="1",CourseName="Softskill 321 : Client Interaction through conference call",CourseImagePath="../../Content/Images/php.png"},


        };
    }
    public List<ROC> GetAllRocDetails() 
    {
        return roc;
    }
}
```

I need to display the details in my view as HTML table.

Edit:

Currently I am getting an output like,

```
[{"CourseId":"1","CourseName":"Softskill 321 : Client Interaction through conference call","CourseImagePath":"../../Content/Images/php.png","rating":0}]
```

Need to display in a neatly designed table or div's

Comment: I can suggest that you google `Grid.MVC` but without telling us what you plan to use this question is too broad.

Comment: Hi, I need to design a part of a website where learning details will be displayed. I don't want use Grid..My query is very simple, How to display the Model details which is sent as JSON object by controller, in HTML format..That's it..

Comment: This was a different question 23 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jquery datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) that accepts the JSON as datasource. [See this sample](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/deepObjects.html) which uses the Json source to create a HTML table with extended grid functionalities.

Or

You can build your custom HTML from JsonResult like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760661/jquery-code-to-display-json-response-to-a-html-table-using-append) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901843/display-json-data-in-html-table).